# Realistic 2D air friction in unity

Tags: unity, physics

I want to make an evolution games similar to this old games that was generating cars.
Except I want it to be more realistic.

So I want air friction to impact the speed of my cars, but how do I do that? wind will always be blowing at the same speed and in the same direction.

But my car chassis are random and their angle of attack can change due to the terrain shape (which is also random)

So I cannot apply a drag value, because this drag value change for the angle of attack. instead I must compute a new drag value for each frame.

[image]

Using real world physics might be to much to let the game run smoothly (10-20 cars running at the same time) How would you do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't really have realistic 2d air friction, since there's no air friction between air and a completly 2 dimensional thing, so you either need to define a depth or somehow make it pseudo 3d

Comment: This really depends on what level of realism you want. Realistic aerodynamic simulations can be amazingly complex.

Comment: well I could make them 3D just by extruding the shape in the hidden axis. I'd like something that is able to shape the cars (each generation slight modification to the chassis will be made, the best one is kept).

Comment: couldn't I make a raycast, compute the angle of the reflection and just decide from that angle which force to apply at that point?

I would just do that for each pixels from the front, and either the top or bottom if the car is going up or down